# Linq to read text file

Tags: linq, file-io

I have a text file with contents as:

```
...
*..
*..
...
The vehicle used are:
*Car(Marathi, Nissan, Toyota)..
*Bikes(Yamaha, Hero Honda)
*...
*...
*...so on..

The items used are...
*..
*..
```

Now I need to search for the key word "vehicle" and put the options Car(Marathi, Nissan, Toyota)..), Bikes(Yamaha, hero honda), etc into a list.

i.e. Everything that comes after "*" in a line, must be an item of that list.

Linq must be used or any other means where loops are not allowed.

Comment: Thus you haven't tried to complete this task by yourself, we can do it for you for only $50 (you should donate this money to Wikipedia)

Answer (score 2):

The desired result is not really clear.

If you need a `List<string>`, containing

```
"Car(Marathi, Nissan, Toyota).."
"Bikes(Yamaha, Hero Honda)"
"..."
"..."
"...so on..
```

you could do

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines(@"<pathToYourFile>")
                 //skip lines without "vehicle"
                 .SkipWhile(m => !m.Contains("vehicle"))
                 //skip the line with "vehicle"
                 .Skip(1)
                 //take the following lines starting with an "*"
                 .TakeWhile(m => m.StartsWith("*"))
                 //remove the "*"
                 .Select(m => m.Replace("*", string.Empty))
                 //enumerate to get a List<string>
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Solution is correct, but are you sure OP donated money? :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky still checking my bank accounts... These tax havens are so slow !